# Log table creation using Laravel Events

Tags: laravel, postgresql, events, event-handling, laravel-8

I want to create a log each time when insertion happens to the `files` table. That is, everytime when an insertion to the `files` table happens, an event has to trigger to create a log for it automatically. `Log` table needs to have 3 columns `id`, `fileid` - primary key of files table & `logDetails` ,where the `logDetails` column store a msg like `1 file inserted`.

i have read this - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events and also searched many more , but that couldn't help me to find where should i start. I have created an event page and a listeners page for this. But i don't know what to write in that.The below Controller & model does the insertion to the `files` table well. And where i need ur help is to code for creating a log for this insertion. Any help is much appreciated.

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\FileLogs;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Events\InsertFileLog;

class FileLogController extends Controller
{
    public function insert(Request $request) // insertion
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            [
                
                'orderId'    => 'required|integer', //id of orders table
                'fileId'    => 'required|integer',  //id of file_type table
                'status'    => 'required|string'
            ]
        );

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
        }
        $obj = new FileLogs();
        $obj->orderId=$request->orderId;
        $obj->fileId=$request->fileId;
        $obj->status=$request->status;
        $obj->save();
        //dd($obj->id);
        if($obj->id!=''){
            InsertFileLog::dispatch($order);
            return response()->json(['status'=>'success','StatusCode'=> 200, 'message'=>'Successfully Inserted','data'=>$obj]);
        }
        
        else{
            return response()->json(['status'=>'Failed','message'=>'Insertion Failed'],400);
        }
        
    }
```

**Model**

```
class FileLogs extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table='files';
    protected $fillable = [
        'orderId',
        'fileId',
        'status'
        
    ];
}
```

**Event**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Models\FileLogs;

class InsertFileLog
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $order;
   
    public function __construct(FileLogs $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }
}
```

**Listener**

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\InsertFileLog;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use App\Models\Logs;

class FileLogListener
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
    public function handle(InsertFileLog $event)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**EventServiceProvider.php**

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    
    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        //
    } 
}
```

Comment: you can consider using [this](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v4/introduction) package.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon I am asking about doing this in the very basic level. The link u gave also don't have any details that specify which is the page to place a specific code

Comment: Are you working with models? Perhaps an easier solution to listen to model events (like `created`, what you're looking for) are [Model observers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers).

Comment: @EricLandheer ok.I understood thta i can use observers here. But i'm asking how to fill  the code here in my events & listener pages?

Comment: @EricLandheer What code shall i fill in this events & listeners page to create this log for insertion only ? thats what i 'm asking. Please post that code as an answer if u know what is the code to create such a log.

Comment: I provided an answer, using the `events` and `listeners` as requested. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @EricLandheer No. in the model, i have the table name `files` as am inserting files to it. But where will i specify to insert the logdetails to the `log` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider` offers a way to [register Events and Listeners](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events#registering-events-and-listeners). The key is the `Event`, the values are one or multiple `Listeners`. You should update your code to contain the following:

**EventServiceProvider**

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
        InsertFileLog::class => [
            // Listeners in this array will be executed when InsertFileLog was fired.
            FileLogListener::class
        ],
    ];


    public function boot()
    {
        //
    } 
}
```

The `FileLogListener` will only be triggered after the event `InsertFileLog` was fired. To do that, you could do the following, by adding: `InsertFileLog::dispatch($order);` line before return success response in your `insert` function.

**FileLogController**

```
class FileLogController extends Controller
{
    public function insert(Request $request) // insertion
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            [
                
                'orderId'    => 'required|integer', //id of orders table
                'fileId'    => 'required|integer',  //id of file_type table
                'status'    => 'required|string'
            ]
        );

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
        }
        $obj = new FileLogs();
        $obj->orderId=$request->orderId;
        $obj->fileId=$request->fileId;
        $obj->status=$request->status;
        $obj->save();
        //dd($obj->id);
        if($obj->id!=''){
            InsertFileLog::dispatch($obj);
            // alternatively, the event helper can be used.
            // event(new InsertFileLog($obj)); 
            return response()->json(['status'=>'success','StatusCode'=> 200, 'message'=>'Successfully Inserted','data'=>$obj]);
        }
        
        else{
            return response()->json(['status'=>'Failed','message'=>'Insertion Failed'],400);
        }
    }
}
```

**FileLogListener**

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\InsertFileLog;
use App\Models\Log;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

class FileLogListener
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    
    public function handle(InsertFileLog $event)
    {
        // $event->order contains the order.
        // In your question, you have request an example of creating an insertion to the Log table
        Log::create([
            'fileId' => $event->order->fileId,
            'logDetails' => '1 file inserted',
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Model observers**

Alternatively, [Model observers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers) provide a solution without having to manually register events/listeners, as they listen to `Eloquent events` of the observed model like: `creating`, `created`, `updated`, `deleted`, etc.

Comment: in this, where shall i specify to create a new row in `logs` table

Comment: The `handle` function of `FileLogListener`. That is the function of the listener that is triggered after the `InsertFileLog` was fired. Does that make sense?

Comment: can u write what code shall i put in that handle method?

Comment: in the model, i have the table name `files` as am inserting files to it. But where will i specify to insert its logdetails to the `log` table? -This is my underlying question

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example of creating a `Log` in the `FileLogListener` (assuming that is a model in your project). Does this answer your question?

Comment: Am getting the error `Undefined Variable :order` for my controller. The `InsertFileLog` event namespace is imported in my controller. Why still that error?

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. You used the `$order` variable in your Event. Please rename the `$order` in the `FileLogController` to `$obj`. Example above was updated accordingly.

Comment: `Class 'App\\Listeners\\Log' not found` - got this error

Comment: You should include your `Log` model. add `use App\Models\Log` as import to your listener above your class opening.

Comment: it is already imported in the listener ,still that error exists

Comment: in listeners page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234765/discussion-between-eric-landheer-and-m-g).